# how to use generated code from matlab

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

I want to use the C-coder in Matlab. This translates an m-code to C-code.
I use a simple function that adds 5 numbers.
When the code is generated there are a lot of C- and H-files.
of course you could just pick the code you need and import it in your code, but that's not the point of this exercise, as this will no longer be possible when the matlab-code will get more difficult.

Matlab delivers a main.c file and a .mk file.

```
/* Include Files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "som.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "som_terminate.h"
#include "som_initialize.h"

//Declare all the functions

int main(int argc, const char * const argv[]){
(void)argc;
(void)argv;

float x1=10;
float x2=20;
float x3=30;
float x4=40;
float x5=50;
float result;

/* Initialize the application.
 You do not need to do this more than one time. */
som_initialize();


main_som();

result=som(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
printf("%f", result);

 som_terminate();
 return 0;
```

}

When I run this on a raspberry-pi with

```
gcc -o test1 main.c
```

It gives me undefined references to all the functions...
Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: What is your intention?  Do you wish to build the code on the pi and run it there, or build, (cross-compile), the code on the PC and then just run it on the pi?

Comment: Yes. I'm reading values from an adc and want to perform an fft on this data with C-code generated in Matlab. But I want to start off with a simple example to understand the workflow

Comment: So the code will be generated on a pc, and compiled on the RPI

Comment: Okay it works now! In matlab you can select 'put all the functions in 1 file'. So you get 1 c-file with all the functions from your original m-file in matlab. You can just write a main and put all the c and header files in the same directory and include them in your code. Pretty messy but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it with the generated makefile (the mk file) so it links with the correct Matlab libraries - that's where those functions are defined:

```
$ make -f test.mk
```

Comment: This gives me this error: 'som_rtw.mk:264: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.' When I check line 264 in the .mk-file it says : %.obj : $(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src/%.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Fo"$@" $(subst /,\,"$<")

Comment: Did you generate the C-Code under windows and now only transfered the mk and c-file to Raspberry? If so, then it is obviously impossible to compile as the general MATLAB interfacefiles are missing (see in the line above, it tries to find files within $(MATLAB_ROOT)/rtw/c/src/)

Comment: If you are trying to compile the code on another system than it was generated on, you need to copy all the files. However, you need the MATLAB library for the platform you're compiling for. See http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/compiler/ch05ge19.html - especially Stand-alone applications require that the MATLAB C/C++ Math Library be purchased for each platform where the Compiler-generated code will be executed.

Comment: I generate the code in windows, but I select that the code is for a device with an ARM Cortex chip. Then I put all the files in a directory on the raspberry-pi and run the make command which gives me the error

Comment: There will be no libraries that you need on the Pi. The link for the libraries above is for the product MATLAB Compiler, not MATLAB Coder. You can use [`packNGo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/package-code-for-other-development-environments.html?searchHighlight=packngo) to package up the code and other files.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to compile the other C files along with your `main.c`. If `main.c` is in the same directory as the generated code, you should be able to just do:

```bash
gcc -o test1 *.c
```

If the generated code is in another directory, then you can do something like:

```bash
gcc -o test1 /path/to/code/*.c -I/path/to/code main.c
```